# Trying to comunicate my nucleo-F411 with a NOKIA5110 display using SPI and DMA

Tags: stm32

I did successfully sent data to the display in my main function.
Working code.

```
uint8_t data[6] = {0x21, 0xB8, 0x04, 0x14, 0x20, 0x0C};
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RST_GPIO_Port, RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RST_GPIO_Port, RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DC_GPIO_Port, DC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CE_GPIO_Port, CE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi2, data, sizeof(data));

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

But when I try to put the initialization code of the display in a diferent file, it won't display anything.The file that contains my initiation function function.

```
#include "5110.h"

struct LCD_PINS lcd_pins;

void set_RST(GPIO_TypeDef *Port, uint16_t Pin){
    lcd_pins.RSTPort = Port;
    lcd_pins.RSTPin = Pin;
}

void set_CE(GPIO_TypeDef *Port, uint16_t Pin){
    lcd_pins.CEPort = Port;
    lcd_pins.CEPin = Pin;
}

void set_DC(GPIO_TypeDef *Port, uint16_t Pin){
    lcd_pins.DCPort = Port;
    lcd_pins.DCPin = Pin;
}

void set_SPI(SPI_HandleTypeDef *Handle){
    lcd_pins.hspi = Handle;
}


void LCD_init(){
    uint8_t data[6] = {0x21, 0xB8, 0x04, 0x14, 0x20, 0x0C};

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(lcd_pins.RSTPort, lcd_pins.RSTPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(lcd_pins.RSTPort, lcd_pins.RSTPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(lcd_pins.DCPort, lcd_pins.DCPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(lcd_pins.CEPort, lcd_pins.CEPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(lcd_pins.hspi, data, sizeof(data));

}
```

When I call the LCD_init, instead of using what is in my main, the display does not initiate properly. Any sugestion of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The relevant parts of the code is still missing. The struct declaration and calling of set_xxx and lcd_init.

Comment: That's the problem, when i call lcd_init, instead of using the code that's in the main now, it stop working, and the struct declaration is in the .h file.

Comment: Yes but you need to call all the setup functions before LCD_init because it needs the things set up. If you don't do that, LCD_init has no way of working. Post the full code that does not work!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Make `uint8_t data[6] = {0x21, 0xB8, 0x04, 0x14, 0x20, 0x0C};` global variable instead of local in `LCD_init`.

DMA transfers data on background and all data and pointers must remain valid over whole time when data are transmitting. So your `data` variable must remain valid not only when calling `HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA` but also after call until all data are transmitted. Because you allocated it as a local variable, compiler allocated it on the stack and when `LCD_init` completes, variable is not valid anymore. Later some code running after your `LCD_init` overwritten the place in the same memory of the stack and DMA transfered wrong data to the display. In your first case it worked well because you defined data as a global variable. Global variables remain valid for a whole execution time.